# Excel dynamic referencing in an array

Tags: arrays, excel

I have an Array and I want the cell references contained in a `SUMIF` to be dynamic, in so much as I want the main holdpoint of data to remain the same, but as I drag the formula down, I want the row reference to change with it

i.e. My main data lives in Cells `A1:D5` theses are a set of prices that are all different

I have table that is manually updated with a series of characters and completed in Cells `A10:D20` depending on what character is used, the correct price is returned

Basic formula is `=SUM(IF(A10:D10="l",1*$A$1:$D$1,0))+SUM(IF(A10:D10="N",1*$A$2:$D$2,0))+SUM(IF(A10:D10="z",1*$A$3:$D$3,0))+SUM(IF(A10:D10="p",1*$A$4:$D$4,0))+SUM(IF(A10:D10="u",1*$A$5:$D$5,0))`

So I want to move down a row to row 11 and have the relative references change accordingly to say `=SUM(IF(A11:D11="l",1*$A$1:$D$1,0)).............etc`

I just can't see how to do it and if an array is in fact the correct way of doing so

Any thoughts?

Comment: the row reference should change. what is the exact problem that you are facing?

Comment: When I "drag" the reference down, nothing changes. If I edit the formula on any row it changes all the rows. I forgot to mention and add to my formula that it is contained within the {} idicating an array formula

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do this with arrays being that the whole point of arrays is to apply a formula on a single set of data (the array).

Comment: That is what I thought, but I was hoping I can simply "hold" the collection of data and then simply reference it using the value in the rows below.

Comment: Oh but I think you don't need array formulas at all. You can just find HLOOKUP and check using IFERROR (excel 2007) or IF(ISERROR (excel 2003)) to know if the character was found or not. The range can be left not being an array.

Comment: In fact, in this case I think it's a bit overkill to use arrays :)

Comment: I inherited this workbook, I have found a much easier way now. using SUMIF and naming my ranges I managed to get it to work as intended and no need for arrays!! YAY! Thanks all for your help and input into this, got me really thinking about other ways to attack it